# My constructor is not working can anyone help me figure out the issue?

Tags: java

The constructor doesn't seem to put the value into the expression variable. If it does it doesn't pass it to tokenizer correctly. When I debug it seems to just pass up the lines inside the constructor. The way I understand the code I wrote is the constructor is called in main() the string should be stored in the expression variable inside parser then expression should be passed to Tokenizer() but the expression variable is null when its passed. I need the string to be stored in the expression variable before it is passed to Tokenizer().

```
public class Parser {
    String expression;
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);

    Parser(String e) {
        this.expression = e;
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Parser parser = new Parser("3+5");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

During initialization of an object, fields are initialized first. So in the fields

```
String expression;
Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);
```

the value of `expression` passed as an argument to the `Tokenizer` constructor is actually the default value `null`.

You need to initialize the `Tokenizer` field after `expression` has been initialized correctly/fully, ie. in your class' constructor.

```
Parser(String e) {
    this.expression = e;
    this.tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression /* or e */);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression); //here is the problem.

you are creating the Tokenizer with Null expression

```
public class Parser {
    String expression;
    Tokenizer tokenizer =null;

    Parser(String e) {

        this.expression = e;
        tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Parser parser = new Parser("3+5");
}
```

Comment: And don't be afraid of passing expression to the tokenizer, Strings are immutables :-)